# Scrapy handshake failure using TLSv1.0 through a proxy

Tags: python, ssl, web-scraping, proxy, scrapy

I am currently trying to develop a web crawler using Scrapy to scrape a website which is not accessible outside of my company. The problem is that I have to go through a proxy, which I succeeded and I was able to run my spider on "http://quotes.toscrape.com". The problem is that the website where I should run it is using TLS 1.0 and I tried several solution which do not work :

**First Solution :**

```
import scrapy
from w3lib.http import basic_auth_header

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = "quotes"
   def start_requests(self):
       urls = [
           'https://10.20.106.170/page.aspx'
       ]
       for url in urls:
           yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse,
            meta={'proxy': 'http://<my_proxy_url>:<my_proxy_port>'},
            headers={'Proxy-Authorization': basic_auth_header('<my_id>', '<my_pwd>')})

   def parse(self, response):
       page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
       filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
       with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
           f.write(response.body)
       self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

**The Output :**

```
    2018-09-26 14:38:00 [twisted] CRITICAL: Error during info_callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1etiennr\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\twisted\protocols\tls.py", line 315, in dataReceived
    self._checkHandshakeStatus()
  File "C:\Users\1etiennr\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\twisted\protocols\tls.py", line 235, in _checkHandshakeStatus
    self._tlsConnection.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\1etiennr\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1906, in do_handshake
    result = _lib.SSL_do_handshake(self._ssl)
  File "C:\Users\1etiennr\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1288, in wrapper
    callback(Connection._reverse_mapping[ssl], where, return_code)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "C:\Users\1etiennr\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_sslverify.py", line 1102, in infoCallback
    return wrapped(connection, where, ret)
  File "C:\Users\1etiennr\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\tls.py", line 67, in _identityVerifyingInfoCallback
    verifyHostname(connection, self._hostnameASCII)
  File "C:\Users\1etiennr\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\service_identity\pyopenssl.py", line 47, in verify_hostname
    cert_patterns=extract_ids(connection.get_peer_certificate()),
  File "C:\Users\1etiennr\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\service_identity\pyopenssl.py", line 75, in extract_ids
    ids.append(DNSPattern(n.getComponent().asOctets()))
  File "C:\Users\1etiennr\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\service_identity\_common.py", line 156, in __init__
    "Invalid DNS pattern {0!r}.".format(pattern)
service_identity.exceptions.CertificateError: Invalid DNS pattern '10.20.106.170'.

2018-09-26 14:38:00 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET https://10.20.106.170/link.aspx> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure service_identity.exceptions.CertificateError: Invalid DNS pattern '10.20.106.170'.>]
2018-09-26 14:38:00 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://10.20.106.170/link.aspx>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure service_identity.exceptions.CertificateError: Invalid DNS pattern '10.20.106.170'.>]
2018-09-26 14:38:00 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-09-26 14:38:00 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 6,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 6,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 1548,
 'downloader/request_count': 6,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 6,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 26, 12, 38, 0, 338000),
 'log_count/CRITICAL': 6,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 7,
```

After discovering that the website uses TLS 1.0, I tried to add a custom setting like this :

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = "quotes"
    custom_settings = {
    'DOWNLOADER_CLIENT_TLS_METHOD' : 'TLSv1.0'
    }
   def start_requests(self):
       urls = [
           'https://10.20.106.170/page.aspx'
       ]
       for url in urls:
           yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse,
            meta={'proxy': 'http://<my_proxy_url>:<my_proxy_port>'},
            headers={'Proxy-Authorization': basic_auth_header('<my_id>', '<my_pwd>')})

   def parse(self, response):
       page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
       filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
       with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
           f.write(response.body)
       self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

Unfortunately, after doing this I get the same error and I don't know what I could do to unstuck myself.

If you have an idea, I'll gladly take it !

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a [bug](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3029) and it has already been [solved](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3029#issuecomment-402196132) on scrapy version [1.5.1](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/news.html#scrapy-1-5-1-2018-07-12).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after doing some more research on the web,I found on that [git issue](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2324) someone having a similar problem. Updating Scrapy to 1.5.1 and downgrading Twisted to 16.6.0 did the trick. I have now another issue but this one seems fixed.